# Ler dois números em uma única linha no Portugol Studio

Tags: input, portugol, portugol-studio

Vou participar de uma competição em alguns dias, e para entrada de dados é necessário que seja feito um `input` de mais de um valor na mesma linha. Por exemplo: Ao invés do usuário informar o primeiro valor, pressionar o enter e informar o próximo, ele informaria direto "`5 2`".

Em *C*++ e em Java é possível fazer mais ou menos assim:

```
int valores[2];

for(int i = 0; i<2; i++){
    cin>>valores[i];
}
```

Mas esse mesmo esquema não funciona no Portugol Studio.

Comment: Já viu os exemplos recomendados no site oficial? Como faria em qualquer linguagem, você pode apenas receber a entrada com um separador (ex: `5 2`), separador `espaço` e depois usar um laço para recuperar os valores. *obs: não uso/usei o Portugol Studio, apenas tomei por base os vídeos deles de documentação*

Comment: Portugol é o mesmo do pseudo- código com comando leia()?

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta

Comment: Lamento não poder chegar à tempo de sua competição, mas, segue a resposta detalhada de como resolver esse problema utilizando o *Portugol Studio*.

Answer (score 2):

No Portugol, os [tipos de dados](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ybMQQZtOys) que utilizamos para aprender lógica de programação são do tipo primitivo(*fazendo uma analogia com outras linguagens de programação*), ou seja, não representam uma Classe e, consequentemente, não possui um escopo com atributos e métodos que são muito úteis. Sendo assim, para resolver o seu problema, utilizei a Biblioteca `Texto` para poder utilizar algumas funções e chegar ao seu resultado esperado. Vale lembrar que no código que implementei, você pode digitar quantos valores achar necessário, separando-os por <kbd>space</kbd>(*visto em seus comentários*).

Segue o código:

```
programa
{   //Considerar a biblioteca Texto como o atributo *tx*
    inclua biblioteca Texto --> tx

    funcao inicio()
    {
        cadeia respostaCompleta
        inteiro tamanho
        cadeia numero = ""

        escreva("Digite uma sequência de números, separando-os por espaço: ")
        leia(respostaCompleta)

        respostaCompleta = respostaCompleta + " "

        inteiro tamanhoResposta = tx.numero_caracteres(respostaCompleta)

        //Loop que varre os caracteres armazenados na resposta.
        para (inteiro contador = 0; contador < tamanhoResposta ; contador ++) 
        {
            //Concatena o número atual com o seguinte(para os números com mais de um dígito, ex:55, 130...), caso não tenha espaço separador.
            numero = numero + tx.obter_caracter(respostaCompleta, contador)
                se 
            (
                //Separa os números digitados por espaço, para exibí-los.
                tx.obter_caracter(respostaCompleta, contador) == ' '        
            )
            { 
                escreva("Seu número foi: ", numero, "\n") 
                numero = ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A ideia foi utilizar a função `numero_caracteres` da biblioteca importada para poder varrer os caracteres da resposta e verificar com `obter_caracter` se há <kbd>espace</kbd> separadores dos números.

**Nota**: Vale lembrar que para capturar a sua resposta, utilizei o *datatype* `cadeia`, uma vez que o tipo `inteiro` como o nome já diz, só aceita valores inteiros e, números separados por espaços não são considerados números inteiros para o *Portugol Studio*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Para essa resposta, utilizei a versão **v2.7.2** do Portugol Studio*.